# Modifying a watched value within a $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-watch

I have an `<input ng-model='list' ng-list>`, and I want to make sure that no duplicates appear in this text field—I want to automatically remove them if the list contains duplicates.

I put a `$scope.$watch('list', function(listValues) {` in the controller, and try to remove any duplicates from `listValues`, but have problems. From within the watch function, if I set `listValues = _.unique(listValues)`, `$scope.list`'s value never changes. If I try `$scope.list = _.unique(listValues)`, I get an error about the digest cycle already running.

How can I watch for a scope variable to change, and when it does, perform an operation to change that new value?

Here's an example of it not working: http://plnkr.co/edit/b0bAuP1aXPg3HryxCD9k?p=preview

I thought this would be simple. Is there some other approach that I should be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) is probably a better approach in this case.  In particular, this attribute of `ng-change`:

> if the model is changed programmatically and not by a change to the
>   input value

If you place your de-dupe in a function and then use `ng-change` to call it, I think you will get the results you are after.